# Pandas: Vectorize for loop when values are interdependent and based on prior values?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, optimization

Since for loop takes so long for data of several Mb, I have to optimize the procedure by vectorization. But I haven't found any good solution on my situation as below.

```py
data = {'A':[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
       'B':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['C'] = 0
df['D'] = 0

# for loop updating column C&D 
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i,'D'] = 0 if (df.loc[i,'B'] == 0) else df.shift().loc[i,'C'] if (df.shift().loc[i,'C'] != 0) else 0
    df.loc[i,'C'] = df.loc[i,'A'] if (df.loc[i,'A'] != 0) else 0 if (df.loc[i,'D'] != 0) else df.shift().loc[i,'C']
```

I want to find the most efficient way to update column C and D as above.

Desired result can be like this below:

```py
   A  B    C    D
0  0  0  NaN  0.0
1  0  1  0.0  NaN
2  1  0  1.0  0.0
3  0  0  1.0  0.0
4  1  0  1.0  0.0
5  0  0  1.0  0.0
6  0  0  1.0  0.0
7  0  1  0.0  1.0
8  0  1  0.0  0.0
```

**Notice:**

**1. C and D are interdependent**

**2. C and D are calculated based on the previous row**

Hope iteration is not the only way though it seems to be.

Comment: If there is no better solution, I'm gonna try: 1. numba JIT 2. itertuple though may not effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.shift()` shift the whole dataframe for each iteration which is very inefficient. Besides this `loc` tends to be quite slow. You can do it once. In fact, you do not need to create a new dataframe, you can store the result in temporary variables or use `i-1` (with a conditional). Note that thr CPython *interpreter* make almost no optimisation so repeated expressions are recomputed many times. That being said, Pandas/Numpy direct indexing is very slow and such code will be much faster with Numba. Note that Numba does not support Pandas, so you have to convert columns to Numpy array with for example `df['A'].to_numpy()` before calling the Numpy function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try these optimization you mentioned. Should I try replacing for-loop to itertuple()? And vectorization(calculating whole data once) is not possible in this scenario so I can only think about how to optimize the iteration right?

Comment: I am not sure itertuple will be really useful here. For vectorization, it seems a bit tricky here because of the apparent dependency chain. Honestly, using Numba+Numpy should give you much better performance anyway. I expect the code to be 2 or 3 order of magnitude faster with Numba (as long as the algorithm is optimized and Numba used properly).